# Writing the same config for different targets in Grunt

Tags: coffeescript, handlebars.js, gruntjs

I have a task with different targets on my Gruntfile, and all targets contain exactly the same fields changing just the name. Is it possible to create these targets programmatically, passing just the list of targets?

My goal is to create a list of submodules installed and create a task with a target for each submodule. To be specific, the task is not mine, I'm trying to create targets for a coffee task to compile some files, but I will also need to do the same with handlebars templates later on.

I've tried creating a generic target and passing the submodule name like this:

```
grunt.initConfig(
    task: {
        target: {
            expand: true,
            flatten: true,
            cwd: "<%= AppModulesPaths[grunt.task.current.args[0]] %>" #"<%= frontend_src %>",
            src: ["<%= AppModulesSources[grunt.task.current.args[0]]%>"],
            dest: "<%= frontend_tmp %>",
            rename: function(dest, src){
                return dest + "<%= grunt.task.current.args[0] %>.js"
            }
       }
    }
})
```

And then register a task array with task:target:targetname but it's complaining about args being undefined.

Is there a good way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Of course, it's just plain JavaScript.

```
function config (targets) {
  var result = {};

  targets.forEach(function (target) {
    result[target] = {
      // target configuration here, 
      // optionally tailored to the target's name
    };
  });

  return result;
}
```

Then, just use it

```
grunt.initConfig({
  task: config(['target', 'target2', 'target3', 'targetN'])
});
```

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9RJun/)

Comment: Thanks! But it's still not working. When calling config from initConfig it says "undefined is not a function." I tried defining the function before and after the call to initConfig (but outside), no luck

Comment: Check out example fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/9RJun/ You probably already had a config variable, I renamed that to `multi` so you don't get name clashing

Comment: In my code I named the function coffeeConfig and it was not working. I've found a workaround, creating a Javascript object with all the properties and after everything is set (including the function call), calling initConfig with that object. Can I change your code to give it as an answer?